Turntable rotation after changing keymap

Hi. I'm creating my own custom keymap which is far more intuitive for me. So when I press E (which is my rotation now) and then press R (which is my scaling), a red/green cursor appears and I can rotate this object on all axes. Blender still recognize combination E-R as double clickin rotation key. I looked for it in the keymap but I can't find what it is exactly.

It's called "Trackball" (as shown in the top left corner of the screen). The search for the keymap doesn't seem to be able to find it. But you can find it if you search for the 'R' key binding for rotation ('E' in your case, I guess). It's in 3D View > Object Mode > 3D View Tool: Rotate > [X] Rotate > Transform Modal Mode > [X] Trackball -> (R)

Yeah it's called "Trackball" you are right. "ut you can find it if you search for the 'R' key binding for rotation ('E' in your case, I guess). It's in 3D View > Object Mode > 3D View Tool: Rotate > [X] Rotate > Transform Modal Mode > [X] Trackball -> (R) –
" sorry but I can't find it on my screen. Can you post a screenshot where it is exactly?

It's called "Trackball" (as shown in the top left corner of the screen). The search for the keymap doesn't seem to be able to find it. But you can find it if you search for the 'R' key binding for rotation ('E' in your case, I guess).
It's in the User Preferences > Key Map, there expand 3D View
> Object Mode > 3D View Tool: Rotate > ☑ Rotate > Transform Modal Mode > ☑ Trackball → R

expand ☑ Rotate and scroll down, there you find Transform Modal Mode ...


Unfortunatelly your solution doesn't work.

what does not work? Does E-R still activate the trackball mode?

Yes. E - R still activate the trackball rotation mode.
